# How to automatically add vpc and region parameters into YAML file for deploying ingress controller?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

Context:
I have been successful in setting up an eks cluster using eksctl with the help of AWS's [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/what-is-eks.html). The subsections that were main useful to me are:

1. clusters
   > creating a cluster
2. Networking
   > pod networking
   > Installing AWS LB controller.
3. workloads
   > application load balancing

Now I am trying use the same command that I learnt from those subsection to write a shell script and automate the entire setup process up until the sample app deployment.

I am stuck where I have to find out the VPC id and region code created via the eksctl and fill them into the `v2_4_3_full.yaml` file. (This file creates all the components necessary to provision an ingress component under the working namespace in Kubernetes).

I feel totally blank when I think of ways to automatically do that instead of manually referring the vpc and region ids.

Below is the part of the YAML file where that has to be done. **Not only do the valueS have to be filled in automatically but even the corresponding parameters have to be added in.** Those parameters will be the last two from below under `args`. I haven't a clue on how to achieve that.

```
spec:
      containers:
        - args:
            - --cluster-name=your-cluster-name
            - --ingress-class=alb
            - --aws-vpc-id=vpc-xxxxxxxx
            - --aws-region=region-code
```

I am not sure what ways exist if they do. But I imagine it would be some shell command that I don't know or some python package that does that. Nonetheless, any suggestion is greatly appreciated.